# cocos2D-X app works on Android but crashes on iOS

Tags: android, ios, ios6, cocos2d-x

the function is not properly calibrated but it "work" (at least on android)

```
void HelloWorld::continueshipMovement() {


    CCNode *node = this->getChildByTag(asterioTag);
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)node;



    if (trafico.size() < 0 or sprite->getActionByTag(actionTag)) {
        return;
    }

    std::pair<float, float> valueOfPt = trafico.back();
    trafico.pop_back();
    CCPoint newPt = ccp(valueOfPt.first, valueOfPt.second);
    float distace = ccpDistance(sprite->getPosition(), newPt);
    float duration = distace / ShipSpeed;
    CCMoveTo *move = CCMoveTo::create(duration, newPt);
    CCSequence *moveseq = CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(move, CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(HelloWorld::continueshipMovement)));
    moveseq->setTag(actionTag);
    sprite->runAction(moveseq);



}
```

the app on IOS crashes when i touch the screen, it seems to fail when cast from CCNode to CCSprite.

here is the error that Xcode shows :

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: What's the error saying?

Comment: Breakpoint is not an error.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, it helped a lot! :) (this is not sarcasm, I'm serious)

Comment: enable global exception breakpoints in Xcode, then try again

Comment: First of all please give a check for NULL for your node and sprite both ..